# Do locally set Cython compiler directives affect one or all functions?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I am working on speeding up some Python/Numpy code with Cython, and am a bit unclear on the effects of "locally" setting (as defined [here](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/reference//compilation.html) in the docs) compiler directives. In my case I'd like to use:

```
@cython.wraparound (False) #turn off negative indexing
@cython.boundscheck(False) #turn off bounds-checking
```

I understand that I can globally define this in my `setup.py` file, but I'm developing for non-Cython users and would like the directives to be obvious from the `.pyx` file.

If I am writing a `.pyx` file with several functions defined in it, need I only set these once, or will they only apply to the next function defined? The reason I ask is that the documentation often says things like "turn off `boundscheck` for this function," making me wonder whether it only applies to the next function defined.

In other words, do I need to do this:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_FLOAT_t

@cython.wraparound (False) #turn off negative indexing
@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn off bounds-checking
def myfunc1(np.ndarray[DTYPE_FLOAT_t] a):
    do things here

def myfunc2(np.ndarray[DTYPE_FLOAT_t] b):
    do things here
```

Or do I need to do this:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_FLOAT_t

@cython.wraparound (False) #turn off negative indexing
@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn off bounds-checking
def myfunc1(np.ndarray[DTYPE_FLOAT_t] a):
    do things here

@cython.wraparound (False) #turn off negative indexing
@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn off bounds-checking
def myfunc2(np.ndarray[DTYPE_FLOAT_t] b):
    do things here
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html#globally) states that if you want to set a compiler directive globally, you need to do so with a comment at the top of the file. eg.

```
#!python
#cython: language_level=3, boundscheck=False
```

Comment: ...or in the `setup.py`.

Answer (score 2):

The manual does not say explicitly, but these directives are using [decorator notation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/).  In plain Python,

```
@decorator2
@decorator1
def fn(args):
    body
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
def fn(args):
    body
fn = decorator2(decorator1(fn))
```

So my *expectation* is that the directives work like that, which would mean that they apply only to the next function.

The Cython manual also says that the compiler directives can be used in `with` statements.  What it *doesn't* say, unfortunately, is whether those can appear at top level:

```
with cython.wraparound(False), cython.boundscheck(False):

    def myfunc1(np.ndarray[DTYPE_FLOAT_t] a):
        do things here

    def myfunc2(np.ndarray[DTYPE_FLOAT_t] b):
        do things here
```

might be what you're looking for, or then again it might be a syntax error or a no-op.  You're going to have to try it and see.

Comment: After testing a code sample, it appears that using the `with` statement at the top level does not apply the directive to the functions, and that you are right that the decorators need to be added before _each_ function. This is confirmed by a ~10% speedup when I use the decorators before each function.