# Cython and Changing Directives

Tags: python, cython

I want to change directives to `wraparound = false`, `nonecheck = False` but how can I do this? I don't know which file I should change.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39183975/1844376

Comment: @ScottMcC which file? I tried with setup but didn't worked